# Error when inline Javascript is moved to external file - how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

There are dozens of similar questions here on stackoverflow, but I can't find an answer that works. I have a couple of Javascript functions that I'm using repeatedly in multiple pages, so I thought it would be a good idea to move them to external file(s). But when I do, they don't work.

Here are the two functions I currently have in (separate, for now) external files:

```
function MessageDialog(obj, title, dialogText) {
  //add the dialog div to the page
  $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='messageDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));
  //create the dialog
  $('#messageDialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    close: function(event, ui) { $('body').find('#messageDialog').remove(); },
    buttons:
      {
        'OK': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
  });
}

//Confirmation dialog
function ConfirmationDialog(obj, title, dialogText, okButtonText, cancelButtonText) {
  var confirmed = false;
  if (!confirmed) {
    //add the dialog div to the page
    $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='confirmationDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));
    //create the dialog
    $('#confirmationDialog').dialog({
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      close: function(event, ui) { $('body').find('#confirmationDialog').remove(); },
      buttons:
        {
          $okButtonText: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            confirmed = true;
            if (obj) obj.click();
          },
          $cancelButtonText: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return confirmed;
}
```

I'm calling `ConfirmationDialog()` from an `OnClientClick` event (in ASP.NET):

`MessageDialog()` is called from code-behind if there's an error on the `btnDelIncident_Click` event:

```
private void DisplayMessageDialog(string msgTitle, string msgText)
{
  StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
  msg.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  msg.AppendFormat("  MessageDialog(this, '{0}', '{1}');" + System.Environment.NewLine, msgTitle, msgText);
  msg.AppendLine("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messageDialog", msg.ToString());
}
```

I'm not getting an error from the `ConfirmationDialog()` call (though the dialog is not appearing), but the `MessageDialog()` call (from the code-behind) results in an "Uncaught ReferenceError: MessageDialog is not defined" in the Javascript console.

I'm including the two external Javascript files in the `<head>` tag, and they're after the jQuery includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ConfirmationDialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MessageDialog.js"></script>
```

I've also tried putting these two `<script>` tags at the end of the page, but it made no difference. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I was able to solve the dialog box problem by wrapping the functions in `(function($) { });` as Neil suggested. Here's the final, working function (declared in an external .js file):

```
//Confirmation dialog
(function($) {
  var confirmed = false;
  ConfirmationDialog = function(obj, title, dialogText, okButtonText, cancelButtonText) {
    if (!confirmed) {
      //add the dialog div to the page
      $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='confirmationDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));
      //create the dialog
      $('#confirmationDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        close: function(event, ui) { $('body').find('#confirmationDialog').remove(); },
        buttons:
        [{
          text: okButtonText,
          click: function() {
              $(this).dialog('close');
              confirmed = true;
              if (obj) obj.click();
           }
         },
         {
           text: cancelButtonText,
           click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
           }
         ]}
      });
    }
    return confirmed;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not want to place script tags in an external JavaScript file. Script tags are HTML elements and a .js file is not HTML. Try wrapping your code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
(function() {

    // your code here    

})();
```

If you are binding function calls to events on DOM nodes, such as 'click' or 'hover' you should make sure the DOM is ready before executing those bindings. jQuery has a method called .ready() which can be used for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Comment: pretty sure he meant he was including the 2 external scripts at the bottom of the page, not that he was adding the script element to the js files

Comment: @Daniel Ward Ah yes, I think you're right :-) Perhaps I read that too quickly. Cheers -- n

Comment: @Neil Girardi I tried your suggestion, and now the confirmation dialog comes up, but pressing the 'OK' button doesn't do anything - the dialog just stays there instead of continuing to execute the ASP.NET Button's OnClientClick action. Another side problem is that the buttons on the dialog literally have "$okButtonText" and "$cancelButtonText" on them instead of the text I'm passing in the function.

Comment: OK, I played around with it some more and got it mostly working. I'll update my original question to show what I changed. The only remaining problem is that the text on my buttons in the confirmation dialog are wrong - the button text is literally "okButtonText" and "cancelButtonText". Is there any way I can make it display the values I'm passing to the function instead of the variable names?

Comment: I finally figured it out - the buttons on my dialogs were not being declared properly (I'm surprised they even worked at all!). They have to be declared as an array: `buttons: [{ text: okButtonText, click: function() { whatever; } }]`. I'll update my original question with the corrected code. I'm going to give Neil Girardi credit for his answer to my original question, that's what led me to the fix. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This should help.  You need to wait until the DOM is loaded before referencing an element in the MessageDialog client-side method

```
  private void DisplayMessageDialog(string msgTitle, string msgText)
    {
      StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
      msg.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
      msg.AppendFormat("jQuery(function($) { MessageDialog(this, '{0}', '{1}'); });" + System.Environment.NewLine, msgTitle, msgText);
      msg.AppendLine("</script>");
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messageDialog", msg.ToString());
    }
```